# SFX Played Once per Collision or Hit

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics, libgdx, sound-effects

I have a question about using Box2D (engine for LibGDX used to make realistic physics). I observed on the code that I've made for the physics here below:

```
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) 
{
      // TODO Touch Up Event

     if(is_Next_Fruit_Touched)
     {
             BodyEditorLoader Fruit_Loader = new BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("Shape_Physics/Fruity Physics.json"));

             Fruit_BD.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
             Fruit_BD.position.set(x, y);

             FixtureDef Fruit_FD = new FixtureDef(); // --> Allows you to make the object's physics.
             Fruit_FD.density = 1.0f;
             Fruit_FD.friction = 0.7f;
             Fruit_FD.restitution = 0.2f;

             MassData mass = new MassData();
             mass.mass = 5f;

             Fruit_Body[n] = world.createBody(Fruit_BD);
             Fruit_Body[n].setActive(true); // --> Let your dragon fall.
             Fruit_Body[n].setMassData(mass);
             Fruit_Body[n].setGravityScale(1.0f);

             System.out.println("Eggs... " + n);

             Fruit_Loader.attachFixture(Fruit_Body[n], Body, Fruit_FD, Fruit_IMG.getWidth());
             Fruit_Origin = Fruit_Loader.getOrigin(Body, Fruit_IMG.getWidth()).cpy();

             is_Next_Fruit_Touched = false;
             up = y;
             Gdx.app.log("Initial Y-coordinate", "Y at " + up);

             //Once it's touched, the next fruit will set to drag.
             if(n < 50)
             {
                 n++;

             }else{

                 System.exit(0);

             }
     }

         return true;
```

}

Now, I'm thinking which part o line should I implement for the sound effects. My objectives to make SFX played once for every collision (Or should I say "SFX played once per collision"?) on the following:

- *SFX played once if they hit on the objects of its kind. (e.g. apple vs. apple)*
- *SFX played once on a different sound when it hit on the ground. (e.g. apple land on the mud)*

Take note that I'm using **Box2D for the Java programming version** thanks to *LibGDX* via *Box2D* engine and I edited the physics body using *Physics Body Editor* before I implement it to code.

I tried to check every available methods for body, fixture definition, or body definition to code for the SFX when hit but it seems only for the gravity and weight. Is there possibly available on the document for SFX played when collision happens if possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see how all that physics code is relevant to playing SFX. (Although you do need collision detection to decide when to play sounds.)

The following design is all pseudocode

In your Apple class body...

```
function onCollisionWith(otherThing)
    if     type(otherThing) == "apple" then playSound("bonk!") end
    elseif type(otherThing) == "mud"   then playSound("splat!") end
end
```

In your collision detection code...

```
thisObjectCurrentlyBeingCheckedFor
    .onCollisionWith(thatObjectItWasFoundToCollideWith)
```

This would produce a sound effect whenever the two objects are colliding.

Depending on how your physics handles the collision, you may want to introduce some state to describe what objects it was *already* colliding with last frame, so you don't re-play the sound.

Comment: This code is good. However, I'm not using C++. I'm currently using Java programming.

Comment: "Pseudocode" is an imaginary programming language. It's only illustrative. It needs to be translated to your programming language to actually do anything. In Java, for example, you might want to define a method in a class `Fruit` like `public void onCollisionWith(Fruit otherFruit)`, containing code similar to the above.

Comment: Translating is like a language, huh? It's more interpreter.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: For example, if you know C++ code, you might familiar with the Java code even though there's a slight difference between the syntax of the two programming languages. Most programmer recognize different programming languages.

Comment: That's right. C++, Lua, Java and JavaScript for example can all be described as "C-like", because all of their syntaxes are quite similar to C. The more of them you know, the easier it is to learn another.

Comment: @David Did you get this to work?

Comment: No. I haven't started yet. Don't worry, I have some codes left for the saving and loading the scores plus the main menu for the game.